# Angular - ng-init checkbox value from controller object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a boolean value to an `ng-init="checked=presenter.present"` so that the checkbox will display checked or not. But it doesn't seem to be passing the value. I've tried `ng-init="checked={{ presenter.present }}"` but I get an error. I will have a lot of checkboxes, so I need to be able to pass a boolean from the controller object to determine whether the checkbox is pre-checked. Any help? Thanks!

`front-end code`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in vm.people">
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns"><input type="text" ng-model="person.name"></div>
    <div class="small-4 large-1 text-center columns">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ person.prid }}" name="{{ person.prid }}" ng-init="checked=person.present" />
            <label for="{{ person.prid }}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns"><input type="text" ng-model="person.notes"></div>
</div>
```

`controller object`

```
    vm.people = [{
        name: 'Evan',
        prid: 'aaa',
        present: true,
        spid: 'aba',
        speaking: true,
        soid: 'abc',
        soundcheck: true,
        notes: 'stuff',
    }, {
        name: 'Amy',
        prid: 'baa',
        present: true,
        spid: 'bba',
        speaking: true,
        soid: 'bbc',
        soundcheck: true,
        notes: 'blah blah',
    }, {
        name: 'Linda',
        prid: 'caa',
        present: true,
        spid: 'cba',
        speaking: true,
        soid: 'cbc',
        soundcheck: false,
        notes: 'blah blah blah blah',
    }, {
        name: 'Tim',
        prid: 'daa',
        present: true,
        spid: 'dba',
        speaking: true,
        soid: 'dbc',
        soundcheck: true,
        notes: 'blah blah blah',
    }];
```

Comment: ng-init should be used sparingly, from the docs: This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try not to use ngInit for petty purposes again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-model` over that check-box element, so that it will automatically get checked or unchecked based on value of `person.present`. Basically two way binding magic of angular will do the trick.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{person.prid}}" 
   name="{{person.prid}}" ng-model="person.present" />
```

Comment: Awesome, that seemed to do the trick! I'll remember that from now on. Thank you for your answer. (I'll accept it as answer in a moment, it's on a timer)

Comment: @Kenny sure, np, Glad to help you, Thanks :-)